# Assembly: what's the difference between `stos m32` and `stosd` mnemonic?

Tags: assembly

In the IA-32 intel instruction set reference, [STOS/STOSB/STOSW/STOSD](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_306.html), what is the difference between the instruction `stos m32` and `stosd`, aren't their description the same?
And what is the function of `m32`? When we use the instruction, we should set the `eax` and `es`, `edi`, does the `m32` operand have effect?

Comment: Might seem odd but using STOS with a memory operand allows the assembler to use the **size** of the memory operand (byte,word,dword) to determine whether to  encode it as STOSB, STOSW, STOSD.

Comment: Then whether the `m32` operand is used or not, it's just used for determining the size of memory operande, so we can select the `m32` operand randomly as long as the size is correct. @MichaelPetch

Comment: It is used solely for the size. What it points at is ignored. Most developers I know use STOSB, STOSW, STOSD. An exception is if you use _MASM_. In that environment when you declare a variable MASM keeps track of the type of variables. End result is the same though - just the size is used.

Comment: ok, I will make a test. Thanks.

Comment: That is the best way to discover it (try some test).

Comment: You're reading a copy of Intel's insn set reference doc, which is excellent.  By reading it more carefully, you could have answered your own question.  Both forms have the same machine-code encoding, i.e. they assemble to the same thing.  Also, the entire 2nd paragraph in the text description is all about why both forms exist, and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The STOS *m32* form and STOSD form are two different ways of expressing the same instruction. You may have noticed that outside of the newer SIMD (SSE, AVX, etc...) instructions, most instruction mnemonics don't have a suffix indicating the size of the operation they perform. For example there's no INCD or MOVW instruction. Instead the size of the operands determines the size of the operation. The STOS *m32* form allows this instruction to be consistent this convention.

In MASM this allows code like following where the size of STOS instruction depends on the type (size) of a symbol:

```
array DW 30 DUP (?)

    mov ecx, LENGTH array
    mov edi, OFFSET array
    mov eax, 1
    rep stos array
```

Change DW to DD and the code will fill an array of DWORDs with 1s instead an array of WORDs. Note that only the size of the memory operand is used. The instruction still writes to the address given by EDI.

While it doesn't apply to STOS, the memory operand forms of certain other string instructions let you override the default DS segment. (The STOS instruction uses the ES segment which can't be overridden.) So for example you can do:

```
    rep outs dx, WORD PTR fs:[esi]
```

Comment: Not only the default segment can be overridden, but also address size with `67` prefix so as to give us e.g. `stos dword [es:di]` in 32-bit mode.